# Can "Basic Magic" be used with Arcane Strike on an (Evolved) Companion

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, druid, animal-companions, eidolon

I started learning Pathfinder a few days ago and decided to make a wild shape druid with a powerful companion.

I'm using the [Evolved Companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/evolved-companion/) feat to grab Basic Magic as a 1 point evolution from the Eidolons pool. My companion is a Cat(big) so it has a base of 10 CHA and can use Basic Magic.

I can either increase my companions INT to 3+ with human trait Eye for Talent or wait for the ability at lvl 4 allowing it to take any feat that it can actually do.

In this case I want to take [Arcane Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/arcane-strike-combat/) to make its natural attacks magic based and gain the +1 attack bonus.

I'm not sure if Arcane strike's prerequisite of "Ability to cast arcane spells" is satisfied by "Basic Magic" since it appears to have arcane spells in the list that can be taking.

I know I know really crazy stuff for a beginner but its how I learn.

**Edit**: I found this [Caster’s Champion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/caster-s-champion-combat/) which is a good substitute to what I was trying to do but only if you have an arcane caster in the group. But for a constant effect you would have to use Evolved Companion and take Magic Attacks (Su) from the Eidolon pool.

Comment: I'd never seen Caster's Champion... that's kind of awesome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No, that combination does not work.

[Basic Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons/#TOC-Evolutions) gives your Eidolon/Companion the ability to *use* a Spell Like *Ability*, not *cast* a spell. It's a very fine distinction, but Paizo has addressed it directly in the FAQ referenced in [this forum post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rzyg?New-FAQ-on-spelllike-abilities). Essentially it specifies that SLA's are not Spellcasting levels nor do they help you qualify for anything that requires 'the ability to cast'.

It used to be allowed before they made a ruling, otherwise a good thought.